# finding longest word in a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the longest word in a non-empty list. My function is supposed to return the longest word. If elements are of equal length in the list, I am trying to sort out the longest in terms of Unicode sorting. For example, I am trying to return the following:

```
    >>> highest_word(['a', 'cat', 'sat'])
    'sat'
    >>> highest_word(['saturation', 'of', 'colour'])
    'saturation'
    >>> highest_word(['samIam'])
    'samIam'
```

So far I can get the first one to work, this is my code so far:

```
    def highest_word(wordlist):
    longestWord = ""
    max_len = 0

    for word in wordlist:

        if len(word) > max_len:
            longestWord = len(word)
            longestWord = word
    return longestWord
```

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple one liner

```
print(max(['a', 'cat', 'sat', 'g'], key=lambda s: (len(s), s)))
```

This works by mapping each element of the list to a tuple containing its length 
and the string itself.

When comparing two tuples `A` and `B`, if `A[0] > B[0]` then `A > B`. Only if `A[0] == B[0]` are the second elements considered. So if the lengths of two strings are equal, then the strings are compared as a tiebreaker.

Comment: Yeah I've tried this before. It doesn't seem to work for the first one. It returns 'cat' instead of 'sat'. It seems to only work for the lists that have only one long word, such as the second one, which returns 'saturation' fine.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate the help alot. Is their a way to mark two answers as correct?

Comment: No. But I strongly encourage you to use this solution. James's answer will work, but it takes time proportional to the length of the list squared (O(N^2)). `max(map(len, a))` iterates over the whole list, and is computed for each element of the list. BAH's answer takes time proptional to the length of the list (O(N)).